# How to find day over day change in summarize table taking two columns into account

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a summarize table that is summed by the Date and Building_Name. I am trying to figure out how to add an increase/ decrease column like my table below. I want to show if the 'total unsigned' has increased from day to day for each building.

I cannot get a formula that will take the previous days total for one building - current days # of total unsigned. Trying to get the forth column for my report.

I can get it to work if I am just showing day over day change if I am not also trying to add the Building_name to the table.

```
Unsigned Prev Day = 
VAR CurrentDay = SELECTEDVALUE(SummarizeTable[Day Number]) 
VAR CurrentMonth = SELECTEDVALUE(SummarizeTable[Month Number]) 
VAR MaxDayNumber = CALCULATE(MAXA(SummarizeTable[Day Number])) 

Return SUMX(
    FILTER(ALL(SummarizeTable),
         IF( CurrentDay = 1, 
          SummarizeTable[Day Number] = MaxDayNumber && SummarizeTable[Month Number]= CurrentMonth-1,
          SummarizeTable[Day Number] = CurrentDay -1)),
            [Total Unsigned])
```

Edit:
Thank you for the help, you definitely put me on the right track. This is the formula I ended up using. Thank you again for the help! [image: Final formula]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Unsigned Prev Day =
VAR MostRecentDate = MAX ( 'SummarizeTable'[Date] )
RETURN
  CALCULATE (
    [Total Unsigned],
    ALL ( 'SummarizeTable'[Date], 'SummarizeTable'[Day Number], 'SummarizeTable'[Month Number] ),
    'SummarizeTable'[Date] = MostRecentDate - 1
  )
```

This assumes that you have or can make a column, 'SummarizeTable'[Date]. If you already have month and day, this should be trivial. This solution takes advantage of the fact that DAX has well-behaved arithmetic on dates.

Additionally, you should look at building a date dimension, rather than doing all of this out of a single table. It will ultimately make your life a lot easier. There are a bunch of good date dimensions out there, but I'm partial to [mine](https://github.com/baldiniunlimited/daxdates).

**EDIT**: Per discussion in comments the goal is to add this as a calculated column to a data table. The definition above is intended to be used as a measure.

```
# Increase/ Decrease =
CurrentRowDate = 'SummarizeTable'[Date]
RETURN
CALCULATE (
  SUM ( 'SummarizeTable'[Total Unsigned] ),
  ALLEXCEPT ( 'SummarizeTable'[Building] ),
  'SummarizeTable'[Date] = CurrentRowDate - 1
)
```

This will add a column to 'SummarizeTable' that has the sum of [Total Unsigned] for the same value of [Building] as is on the current row and with a date 1 less than that on the current row.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. The trouble im running into is once I added the "building name" to the summarize table there are multiple instances of the date on the table now. Would this be remedied by adding a date dimension? My ultimate goal is to show day over day change in a waterfall visualization that can be filtered by building. Thank you for sharing your date dimension,  I just downloaded it an will be incorporating it into my report. Sorry if this is remedial- I'm just starting out.

Comment: Would you please provide a sample of your data table(s) (list the columns in the table, and a couple sample values from each)? And any screengrabs that show what you mean by "When I add 'building name' there are multiple instances of the date"? It is fine for multiple buildings to exist on the same date, and the data tables would reflect that. Do you expect not to have multiple buildings on the same date?

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/wNzHzJo)

So I'm having trouble getting the fourth column. I do expect there to be multiple buildings on the same date. But I only want to show the increase/ decrease DoD for each building. @greggyb

Comment: If there are many dates, then there are many values for DoD increase/decrease. If you want to show just a single date, you can filter to that date. It is still very unclear what you are even trying to do. Are you building a visual in Power BI? Are you building a pivot table in Excel? Are you writing a DAX query? Are you importing data? And again, I'll ask for a sample of your data tables.

Comment: So I am trying to create a table that will be used in a waterfall visualization. I have uploaded 3 documents to show you what I am working with right now. 1) the summary table without 'building' when the DoD calculation works correctly. 2) sum table with 'buildings' where the DoD calculation does not work correctly 3) the end result that I want- a waterfall table that where I can filter by 'building' to show DoD change. [link](https://github.com/jea6883/data.git) @greggyb

Comment: Okay, so this is coming in as a calculated column. Updating my answer.

Comment: @Justine, I'm glad you were able to get this working. A quick note on StackOverflow norms: typically you shouldn't edit a post to respond. I took your proposed edit to the question and added it to the end of your question.